Add-On service rest api
I am trying to upload add on zip using add ons service rest api post method but getting below error in postman. Let me know if anybody faced this or any idea to resolve this?

{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP resource
that matches the request URI 'https://host/addon/api/v1/addons' does
not support the API version '1'.","innerError":null}}


are you able to upload from browser? could you also check request url on network tab on developer mode(F12) of browser when upload from browser

I am able to upload it from swagger UI. What you want me to check in network tab? I have tried from visual studio too using httpclient but that is also not working.

if it works from swagger endpoint, you might want to check "request url", request headers those are being passed, and correct request body form data is being added to http request.

Problem may be in the encoding of the request body; the POST request expects multi-part form data; check the (raw) request Payload and the Content-Type header.

share the screenshot of the postman what header parameters u have used

Important to note that api you are trying to access in postman should be POST method not Get method.

The error message indicates that the API version you are using in the request is not supported. The UnsupportedApiVersion error typically occurs when:

The API endpoint requires a specific version header in the request.
The POST request to the Add-on Service API does not include the correct API version.

If you want to replicate this in Postman, follow these steps:

Authentication:


Send a POST request to your Access Management URL with the body parameters:
 grant_type: client_credentials  
 client_id: <your_client_id>  
 client_secret: <your_client_secret>  


This will return a bearer token.




Add-On Upload:


Use the retrieved token in the Authorization header:
Authorization: Bearer <your_token>

Send a POST request to:



http://<your_addon_service_url>/addon/api/v1/addons


Set the body as form-data and include the file under the file key.



I have also created powershell script to upload the add-on package in case if you are looking for some automation script.
.\UploadTridionAddon.ps1 -AccessManagementUrl "http://access.tridiondemo.com:84/access-management/connect/token" -AddonServiceUrl "http://dxd.tridiondemo.com:83" -ClientId "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx" -ClientSecret "Dqbxxxxxxxxxxx==" -AddonPackagePath "C:\\TridionSites\Content Delivery\roles\content\add-ons\udp-content-connector-framework-extension-assembly-12.2.0-1055-core.zip"

UploadTridionAddon.ps1
I hope it helps
